# jQuery Regex Code With If Statement For Password

Tags: jquery, regex, passwords

I am trying to make an if statement that will test a string in jQuery (or Javascript).  Here are the conditions:

1. Has to be between 6-8 characters.
2. First character cannot be a number.
3. Has to contain 1 number, 1 lowercase letter, and 1 uppercase letter.

Here is my regex code:

```
((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})
```

I tested it on a website that tests regex codes, and it works fine.

Here is my if statement currently:

```
if(((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}).test(strOldPassword))
{
    alert("Something");
}
```

I am getting a syntax error when my webpage loads however, saying that there is a problem with the regex.

Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error 

if(((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8}).test(strOldP

Comment: And I KNOW what a string is.  strOldPassword is a variable that is holding the string.  Don't treat me like an idiot.

Comment: First, you're missing regex delimiters: `/regex/`. Second, you're missing string boundary anchors (at least the end-of-string one): `/^regex$/`

Comment: @snowfi6916: Sorry, that really was rude on my part.  You need to wrap your regex in quotes, such as `"`, or `'`, so it is interpreted as a String.

Comment: Okay I'll try that.  Hang on.

Comment: @mellamokb nope. A string literal is not how you want to represent a regex. A regex literal is much better.

Comment: I have it almost working. It's not working for the correct number of characters though (6-8).  Here it is currently: `if (!(/((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})/.test(strOldPassword)))
   {
    jQuery('#txtOldPassword').addClass('error');
   }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to define a regular expression in JavaScript.

1. Using the `/.../` syntax.

   ```
   /((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})/
   ```
2. By creating an instance of RegExp object which accepts the regular expression as a String in the constructor.

   ```
   new RegExp("((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})")
   ```

That is,

```
if(/((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})/.test(strOldPassword)){
  alert("Something");
}
```

Comment: You don't fix the other issue I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if(/^(?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})$/.test(strOldPassword))
// --                                                --
```

`/.../` delimits a regex literal, so that the parser knows what to parse as regex, not javascript (much like single quotes delimit strings).

`^...$` indicates that the whole string should be matched (otherwise you'd be testing for *at least* 6-8 charactes).

`// -- ... --` is just a comment to indicate what I've chaged.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
if (!(/((?=^[^0-9])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,8})$/.test(strOldPassword)))
{
    jQuery('#txtOldPassword').addClass('error');
}
```

Thanks for the tips guys.